# Woocommerce hook for html after the product summary?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I use [this](https://storecustomizer.com/woocommerce-product-page-hooks-visual-guide/) link as a visual guide for the hooks. I want to display some content at `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary`. So my code is

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'testfunc' ); 
function testfunc() {
    echo "Test"; 
}
```

But for some reason it displays Test between my product title and price. I hardly have any other hooks which could interfere. I've also tried different priorities, but nothing seems to change.

Comment: If you switch themes to basic twentytwenty for example, does the hook show? It might be theme related, because for example I was using Elementor Pro which was blocking this hook.

Comment: Do you have a custom single product page template added in the child theme? The [`woocommerce_after_single_product`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-content-single-product.html#source-view.76) hook is used at the end of the template. If it has been placed in a different place on the page it will be shown there.

Answer (score 0):

Using **add_action** not **add_filter**

Ex:

```
 <?php
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'testfunc', 25 ); 
    function testfunc() {
        echo "Test"; 
    }
?>
```